# How to get layout components not on an Acitivty's own layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, reference, android-view

I'm trying to manipulate components not on an Activity's own layout view. How would I reference them?

I have the resource ID but when I try to reference them using:

```
DatePicker date = ((DatePicker) findViewById(resID));
```

.. I get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get views in different layout xml file, the best practice is to use a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to inflate(load) these files. You can do something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
View firstView;
View secondView;
Button aboutFirst;
Button aboutSecond;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);//initialize the layout inflater
    firstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstview, null); // inflate firstview.xml layout file
    secondView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondview, null);//inflate secondview.xml layout file
    aboutFirst = (Button) firstView.findViewById(R.id.button1);//get button  in firstview.xml
        aboutSecond = (Button) secondView.findViewById(R.id.button1);//get button in secondview.xml
}
```

Comment: This didn't end up working. I want to be able to get the layout but in the state it's in already, for example if a textbox has been filled in, I want an instance of the layout with it filled in, not a new empty version if you get what I mean..

Comment: Wht do you want to do exactly? Please show your context and need. I think you want to get the text from a textbox(TextView?) in another activity?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found to this was to change the current content view to the one that holds the View you're trying to find:

```
setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
DatePicker date = ((DatePicker)findViewById(resID));
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

then changing back to the original layout. I'm still looking for a better solution, but this is what I've got currently.

Comment: As long as you change back to the main layout, I've found it's not noticeable that you even did anything.